# When will dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver start being considered by system?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

My question is about: "when will my postbox be noticed by the postman", not "when will I be able to read any letters"?

I have an `Activity` which allows the user to edit a list. As soon as the user commits the edit, an `IntentService` is started which in turn calls a database helper to change the database entries as required.

As soon as the database is updated successfully (nothing crashed until then), the database helper writes "ok" to `SharedPreferences` and returns to the `IntentService`. The `IntentService` sends a message to a `BroadcastReceiver` which now causes the list to be reloaded from db with the current data.

The `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class of the `Activity` and it is registered dynamically in `onCreate()`:

```
    mReceiver = new MyMessageReceiver();
    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter();
    iFilter.addAction("com.example.mycoolapp.LOCALINTENT");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, iFilter);
```

If the user stayed in my `Activity` until the list could be reloaded, there would be no problem at all. But imagine the user moving around and somehow causing an orientation change...  that's why I have the "ok" in `SharedPeferences`:

In `onCreate()`, after registering the receiver, I check whether there is an action pending:

If the database was updated successfully, I can load the data and just set a flag for my receiver to ignore the next message. Which will come, as the IntentService was configured with `setIntentRedelivery(true)`.

If I find that the database is not yet updated, I decide to wait for the broadcast from the `IntentService`.

The one thing I'm extremely uncertain of is the following:

From which moment on will the system consider my receiver to be "up and running"? I know that `onReceive()` can only be called after `onCreate()` is finished.

Is it possible that while `onCreate()` is being executed, the IntentService fires the local Broadcast ("too soon") and my receiver will never get it?

Then that list would never be refreshed until the user left the `Activity` (which is quite likely) and returned once more (then not so likely).

Answer (score 2):

The Broadcast Receiver is not registered in the Activity but in the main application thread. The registerReceiver method is defined in the Context class.

That means that your Broadcast receiver will remain `registered` until you un-register it or your application is destroyed (ie. not having the receiver in a `Service`)

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter))

> From which moment on will the system consider my receiver to be "up
>   and running"? I know that onReceive() can only be called after
>   onCreate() is finished.

From the moment registerReceiver() returns

> Is it possible that while onCreate() is being executed, the
>   IntentService fires the local Broadcast ("too soon") and my receiver
>   will never get it?

You can avoid this by registering the receiver in the onCreate method of a class that [extends](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)`Application`. That's how you can make sure that the broadcast receiver is the first thing done.